# how to get continous ranking using count(*) over (order by ....) in Oracle

Tags: oracle, count, sql-order-by

I have table a

```
Item
------   
apple
apple
bean
bean
cherry
cherry
cherry
```

I want to create another table with ranking of the items like this below

```
Item    ranking
----------------   
apple      1
apple      1
bean       2
bean       2
cherry     3 
cherry     3
cherry     3
```

I use the statement and can generate ranking like this

select item, count(*) over (order by item) from table a

```
Item    ranking
----------------   
apple      1
apple      1
bean       3
bean       3
cherry     5 
cherry     5
cherry     5
```

Is there a fast way to create the desired continuous ranking?

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Try **DENSE_RANK** function:

```
select item, dense_rank() over (order by item) from table a
```